# How to develop axis2 webservice with spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, apache-axis

```
<service name="demoServiceImpl" scope="application">
    <description>simple spring example</description>
    <schema schemaNamespace="http://www.ylzinfo.com/xsd"/>
    <parameter name="SpringBeanName">demoServiceImpl</parameter>
    <parameter name="ServiceObjectSupplier" locked="false">
        org.apache.axis2.extensions.spring.receivers.SpringServletContextObjectSupplier
    </parameter>
    <operation name="fetchPdfCipher">
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
    </operation>
</service>
```

I know that cxf can develop with spring integration, but I want to know how axis2 integrate with spring?

Answer (score 1):

Your service.xml looks correct. Since`SpringServletContextObjectSupplier`  is being used,  you only need to properly configure the applicationContext.xml in your application's web.xml
Add the `listener` and `contextConfigLocation` in your web.xml and you will be good to go. 
Further documentation is available [here](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/spring.html)

Hope this helps.